# How should Outlook Redemption be used when Basic Authentication is disabled?

Tags: outlook-redemption

Office 365 will turn Basic authentication off in October 2020. I could not find Redemption documentation on Basic vs. Modern authentication.

We are calling `RDOSession.Logon` but have found that unless `AllowBaseAuthAutodiscover` and `AllowBasicAuthMapi` are enabled, the code fails. Some of the errors include "Could not find the store DN" and "MAPI_E_FAILONEPROVIDER".

We need to fully support Modern Authentication and multi-factor authentication (MFA) instead of relying on some features of basic authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version 5.22 will let you use an OAuth token in `LogonHostedExchangeMailbox`: specify the mailbox address (first parameter), leave second parameter r(user name) empty, and pass the OAuth token as the third parameter.